# kerberos ticket decoding returns not correct username

Tags: java, encoding, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I'm struggling with this issue, and every spare time I have I'm looking into this.

We have a SSO working, and for 99% of the users there is no problem.
But, when a username(SAMAccountName) contains accents, we have a problem.

The Kerberos ticket is validated, but we retrieves a bad username.
Example :

SAMAccountName : andré.a
Retrieved principal after validation : andr□□.a

It's certain that it's some encoding problem, because we used to use a windows Kerberos system witch didn't have any problems and now we have a Linux Kerberos what does make this problem.

I'm looking into the code and trying to find a solution but I'm having a feeling it's just some Kerberos setting what need's to be changed or a specific application encoding setting what's need to be altered.

Is there any possibility to decode the principal from the base64 negotiate header without having to trigger the validation itself (because validation works)?

Or, is there someone who had this problem also and did found the solution?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I thought I might have heard of this before.  So I looked and I found only one article which talks about the accent problem (among other things) but it didn't seem to have a straight-forward solution which I thought could apply to your case.  Maybe you can take a look and tell me what you think?  https://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Projects/Aliases#Case_insensitive_and_international_friendly_search

Comment: This looks really hopeful for a solution. I'll share this intern and I hope they will give it a try.
Thanks so much, didn't come up to this document in mine searches.

Comment: Great, don't forget to come back and share any details towards the solution.

Comment: 1 month later => still no feedback and I have mine doubts that someone did some action.